# My email template's variable content block order keeps resetting while creating a campaign in Mailchimp

Tags: html, css, email, templates, mailchimp

I'm having a super annoying problem, and I'm hoping someone else has encountered this and can help me.

I'm creating mc:repeatable and mc:variable blocks in a mailchimp template. When creating a campaign, the order of the variable blocks I call up sticks in that way, even after I make changes via drag and drop.

e.g. Say this is the order of the blocks in a campaign:

```
<title block>
<30 px spacer>
<60 px spacer>
<feature block>
<double feature block>
```

And I drag the `<60 px spacer>` block below the `<feature block>` block.

When previewing and testing, it reverts to the original order of variable blocks.

I cleared my cache, I used an incognito window, I tried everything - but not for hell will this layout maintain the reordered structure.

If I change text within one of the blocks, the changes remain just fine. It's just that the order of these blocks refuses to be changed, and when I hit 'edit' after previewing, it looks like I never reordered the blocks in the first place.

It's driving me completely batty.

Can someone please help?

Comment: maybe this is something for the mailchimp support guys?

Comment: I already sent them a message and after 24 hours of waiting, they assumed I didn't put any mc:variable or mc:repeatable template code in my code, and now I'm waiting for another answer based on my repeating of what I said before, as in, copying and pasting this exact thread (that hopefully doesn't take 24 more hours to arrive).